# Docker NestJS with prisma can't connect to PostGresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, nestjs, prisma

I have a docker compose file, but they can't connect to the db, or to each other.

I tried several things but it keeps complaining it can not connect to the database.

Also changing db to localhost doesn't work.

I just ran: docker-compose up

The error I get is:

```
cinema_1   | 
cinema_1   | > cinema@0.0.1 start:migrate:prod
cinema_1   | > prisma migrate deploy && npm run start:prod
cinema_1   | 
quotes_1   | Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
quotes_1   | Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "quotes", schema "public" at "db:5432"
```

docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  gateway:
    build: ./api-gateway
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  quotes:
    build: ./quotes
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://myuser:mypassword@db:5432/quotes
    ports:
      - 8895:8895

  shows:
    build: ./shows
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://myuser:mypassword@db:5432/shows
    ports:
      - 8893:8893

  db:
    image: postgres:13.5
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    volumes:
      - integration-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  integration-postgres:
```

Comment: What command do you run ? What is the error message about the database connection ?

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: I don't know about NestJS or Prisma but I don't see anything looking wrong.

Comment: Maybe the nestsjs container tries to connect to postgres before db container is up. Try adding ```depends_on``` in the services where db connection is established, so that the db container runs first before other services.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database from outside of docker container?

Comment: Where is your error? I can only see the migration logs as mine are `Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "prisma", schema "prisma" at "127.0.0.1:5432"` This is not an error but the migration

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the thread schema.prisma file ?